# Internet Explorer disable text and text field

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, meta

In my website text and text field are not editable in IE , when i enable compatibility view in IE ,this thing solved my problem but I want to know that is there a way to active compatibility view by coding or meta tag (This is only happening in windows 7 and 8, i have check it on Internet explorer 8 with windows XP it working great)

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" value="" name="discount_id">
```

Comment: Can you post HTML of your text field (element input) or URL of your website?

Comment: '<tr>
 <th>Code:</th>
 <td><input type="text" maxlength="10" value="" name="discount_id"></td>'
</tr>

Comment: What version is doing it? 11 works good.

Comment: it working fine on ie8 in xp, i think windows version is problem, because ie8 on xp is working and ie8 on widows 7 is not working

Comment: focusing in text field is working but other editing is not working , and other text also disable (not select able)

Comment: don't relay on compatibility view, don't even try to debug code with this option (compatibility view)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **NO**

Long answer:  **NO**

you can not force users to have their Internet Explorer browsers go in to compatibility view, by coding.